# Playing a random animation every time an object passed

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I am currently in the process of making a game and I am trying to have a mirror play a random animation as the player walks past it. I managed to get it working, sort-of, and am having some troubles with it.

So first I created an idle animation along with three random animations to be activated as the player walks by and from the idle animation. I then created a simple transition to each of the three states leaving the standard exit time and transition duration on. I than created this script to try to activate the animations:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class mirrorActivate : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject FSSecurity;
    public GameObject mirrorblank;
    public List<AnimationClip> anim = new List<AnimationClip>();
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Awake()
    {

    }
    void Start()
    {
        FSSecurity = GameObject.Find("Female Security");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (FSSecurity.transform.position.x == 10)
        {
            StartAnimation();
        }
    }
    public void StartAnimation()
    {
        int random = Random.Range(0, anim.Count);
        mirrorblank.GetComponent<Animator>().Play(anim[random].name);
    }
}
```

What's working: It is seemingly playing a random animation every time the player walks to this location.

What's not working?: 
1. Upon entering scene idle animation immediately triggers one of the three animations without the if statement being activated. ((It should be in idle and only switch to one of the three randomly if if() is true)) 
2. Due to floating point precision using == is not practical, this theoretically could be solved if I use a range with <= and >= rather than ==. But if there is a better solution to activate the player passing an object I am open to suggestions. 3. Animations when played randomly are not fully playing the full time the animation should last. 4. Final issue after activated they are not returning to idle state until next activation.

What I am looking for: Random animation to play each time user walks passed object and as it finishes return to idle. And as a side note is there a more effective way to know when player passes object (I am using 2D)

(for some reason not letting me put unity2d tag on the post)

[image]

Simple transitions between, no triggers set or anything

[image]

Comment: Could you please paste a screenshot of your animation controller so we can see your transition strategy?

Comment: What do you mean "introducing transitions back to the idle state creates other issues"?

Comment: @AlexMyers I just updated the problems for the final time. Please check above to see final edit. That was a mistake I had made, I had changed a thing in the code too and forgetting that I thought the transitions pointing back to idle state were causing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! After some more long and twisted turns I have finally come up with a reasonable solution that I think works well.

Problem 1 solution:
In order to prevent any animation from triggering before if() statement is tripped, remove transition from Idle to random states.

Problem 2 solution:
Simply used a range to solve issue with comparing floating point precision using ==. Please comment on any other better way to go about this.

Problem 3 solution:
Animations were not fully running their course of the desired animation time because of constant triggering. If the player is >= 10 was the only parameter causing it to activate so to solve use a simple solution of a boolean. If the player.transform is >= 10 and the boolean is true start animation. If the player is outside of the range boolean is false. In StartAnimation() set boolean too true.

Problem 4 solution:
Now with transitions from idle to random animations removed instead create transition from random states to exit. No transitions interacting between idle and random animations are required.

Full code for better details:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class mirrorActivate : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject FSSecurity;
    public GameObject mirrorblank;
    public List<AnimationClip> anim = new List<AnimationClip>();
    bool isPlayingAlready = false;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Awake()
    {

    }
    void Start()
    {
        FSSecurity = GameObject.Find("Female Security");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (FSSecurity.transform.position.x >= 10 && isPlayingAlready == false)
        {
            StartAnimation();
        }
        if (FSSecurity.transform.position.x <= 10 && isPlayingAlready == true)
        {
            isPlayingAlready = false;
        }
    }
    public void StartAnimation()
    {
        int random = Random.Range(0, anim.Count);
        mirrorblank.GetComponent<Animator>().Play(anim[random].name);
        isPlayingAlready = true;
    }
}
```

Animation Controller View:

[image]

Animation Transition View (This may change depending on your needs but for this purpose..):

[image]

I hope this helps anyone who may suffer from these same issues, this can be done with anything that you with to activate random animations whether it be collision or something else.